# cannot fetch custom annotations if class is loaded from jar

Tags: java, maven, annotations, war

I added a Custom java annotation in my WebProject for one of my model class. Now the issue is, if I keep the class in the referred module jar of my project war, I am not able to fetch the field level custom annotations added in the model class. It works fine if the class is kept as part of same project war from where I am fetching all the annotations.I even marked the retention policy as "RUNTIME" but it did not help. Any idea, what is wrong here.

```
public class SalesUploadData {

    @ExcelColumn(position = 0)
    private Integer countryCode;
    @ExcelColumn(position = 1)
    private Integer currencyCode;
    @ExcelColumn(position = 2)
    private String serialNumber;

    public Integer getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(Integer countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }
}

@Documented
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface ExcelColumn {
    String name() default "";
    int position();
    String dateFormat() default "";
    boolean isMandatory() default false;
}
```

I am deploying two WARs in the server as depicted in the below image.

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: You should provide the structure of your modules.

Comment: If you're trying to use a class that's part of a WAR module, and you use Maven, you should use the maven-war-plugin to create an additional artifact containing its classes: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses

Comment: @luc14n0   Yes, I am using maven in my project and the plugin you mentioned is already there in pom.xml to package it as WAR. I have also edited my post with my project structure details you require. Thanks

Comment: Do you use `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` in the plugin configuration?

Comment: @luc14n0 It was not there, I added it now and worked. Thanks a lot. You made my day !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, the solution was to add `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` to the maven-war-plugin to generate an additional artifact containing just the classes of the web module in a *module-classes.jar* archive to use as a dependency in other modules.